# How do I join a column - in a table-variable and that has a function acting on it - to a column in a permanent table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is the code I used to create the table variable

```
DECLARE @attribute_table  
TABLE (attributeId VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, EventId VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, EVENT_TEACHERS VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @attribute_table 
SELECT attributeID, EventId, attributeValue as EVENT_TEACHERS
FROM dbo.retreatSuiteEventAttributes
WHERE attributeName LIKE '%EVENT_TEACHERS%'


select t1.attributeId, t1.EventId, i.EVENT_TEACHERS
from  @attribute_table t1
outer apply dbo.teacherstring3(t1.EVENT_TEACHERS, '|') i
```

(teacherstring3 is a function that basically split the EVENT_TEACHER values into different rows and removed a delimiter)

The answers I am getting are just modifying the above select statement. What I want is to join (or integrate it with) the result of that statement to the main select statement shown fully below.

I want to use the column which has a function acting on it -> i.EVENT_TEACHERS (FK) column to join to another (permanent) table which has the corresponding TeacherIds (PK) in the SELECT statement shown below. 
How do I do this?

This is the full query I am performing after creating the table variable (I'll execute them at the same time). It doesn't work, I am also getting incorrect syntax near GROUP.

```
 SELECT FORMAT(b.eventStartDate, 'd') as 'Start Date',
dbo.CategoryString(CAST(attributeValue as VARCHAR)) as Categories, 
b.EventName as 'Event Name', 
d.FirstName + ' ' + d.LastName as Teacher, 
b.spacesAvailable as Capacity, 
SUM(a.numberOfPlaces) as 'Participants', 
FORMAT(CAST(SUM(a.numberOfPlaces) as FLOAT)/CAST(b.spacesAvailable as FLOAT), 'p') as Occupancy,
FORMAT(SUM(a.totalCost), 'C') as Cost,
FORMAT(SUM(a.totalPaid), 'C') as Paid,
FORMAT(SUM(a.discountAmount), 'C') as Scholarships,
FORMAT(SUM(a.Donation), 'C') as Gifts,
FORMAT(SUM(a.totalPaid)/SUM(a.numberOfPlaces), 'C') as 'Revenue Per Seat'
  FROM [dbo].[RetreatSuiteRegistrations] a join [dbo].[RetreatSuiteEvents] b on a.EventId = b.EventId AND a.registrationStatusId=1 AND b.spacesAvailable > 0
  JOIN [dbo].[RetreatSuiteEventAttributes] c on a.EventId = c.EventId AND c.attributeName='EVENT_CATEGORIES'
  JOIN @attribute_table t1 outer apply dbo.teacherstring3(t1.EVENT_TEACHERS, '|') i
  JOIN [dbo].[RetreatSuiteTeacher] d on  i.EVENT_TEACHERS = d.TeacherID
  GROUP BY b.eventStartDate, dbo.CategoryString(CAST(attributeValue as VARCHAR)), b.EventName, d.FirstName + ' ' + d.LastName, b.spacesAvailable
  ORDER BY b.eventStartDate desc

    DROP Function IF EXISTS CategoryString
go
```

Comment: Could you provide the full query you are having problems with, just looking at what you have written there is nothing obvious causing the problem.  (Presuming you are correctly matching columns)

Comment: Updated with full query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just simply add a dumb subquery like:

```
SELECT
  FORMAT(b.eventStartDate, 'd')                                                          AS [Start Date]
  , dbo.CategoryString(CAST(attributeValue AS VARCHAR))                                  AS Categories
  , b.EventName                                                                          AS [Event Name]
  , d.FirstName + ' ' + d.LastName                                                       AS Teacher
  , b.spacesAvailable                                                                    AS Capacity
  , SUM(a.numberOfPlaces)                                                                AS Participants
  , FORMAT(CAST(SUM(a.numberOfPlaces) AS FLOAT) / CAST(b.spacesAvailable AS FLOAT), 'p') AS Occupancy
  , FORMAT(SUM(a.totalCost), 'C')                                                        AS Cost
  , FORMAT(SUM(a.totalPaid), 'C')                                                        AS Paid
  , FORMAT(SUM(a.discountAmount), 'C')                                                   AS Scholarships
  , FORMAT(SUM(a.Donation), 'C')                                                         AS Gifts
  , FORMAT(SUM(a.totalPaid) / SUM(a.numberOfPlaces), 'C')                                AS [Revenue Per Seat]
FROM dbo.RetreatSuiteRegistrations                                   a
  JOIN dbo.RetreatSuiteEvents                                        b ON a.EventId = b.EventId
                                                                         AND a.registrationStatusId = 1
                                                                         AND b.spacesAvailable > 0
  JOIN dbo.RetreatSuiteEventAttributes                               c ON a.EventId = c.EventId
                                                                         AND c.attributeName = 'EVENT_CATEGORIES'
  JOIN (SELECT
          t1.attributeId
          , t1.EventId
          , i.EVENT_TEACHERS
        FROM @attribute_table                                    t1
          OUTER APPLY dbo.teacherstring3(t1.EVENT_TEACHERS, '|') i ) AS MyTest ON c.EventId = MyTest.EVENT_TEACHERS
  JOIN dbo.RetreatSuiteTeacher                                       d ON MyTest.EVENT_TEACHERS = d.TeacherID
GROUP BY
  b.eventStartDate
  , dbo.CategoryString(CAST(attributeValue AS VARCHAR))
  , b.EventName
  , d.FirstName + ' ' + d.LastName
  , b.spacesAvailable
ORDER BY b.eventStartDate DESC;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS CategoryString;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I am trying to do is join the result of the query ->  select t1.attributeId, t1.EventId, i.EVENT_TEACHERS
from  @attribute_table t1
outer apply dbo.teacherstring3(t1.EVENT_TEACHERS, '|') i .  -> to the rest of the Select query (the full one I show below). How do I integrate them?

Comment: Sorry I get it now, it is just that when I first answered, your edited part wasn't there.

Comment: Thanks! That works.  One thing though you may or may not be able to help me with, but I'll ask anyways. Some of the EventIds in the @attribute_table have multiple EVENT_TEACHER Ids. for example [Row 1] EventId 2101 EVENT_TEACHER 14, [Row 2] EventId 2101, EVENT_TEACHER 15.  the result of this query only seems to show the Events which only had 1 EVENT_TEACHER . Would you know how to fix this?

Comment: If you are happy with my suggestion, please accept it as answer. I'm not sure how to solve your functional issue. Maybe you could amend your question with example data and expected result.